# MapKit not loading mapView

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit

I created a small app with MapKit and it shows the current location on map with an annotation along with another annotation at a different place.

Now, all of this was working fine till I changed the name of folder where my project file was saved. When I changed the name of the folder, the app doesn't crash, but the map just doesn't load. It just gives a black screen.

And there's something even weirder - When I put this name changed folder inside another folder, and then simulate it gives a black screen for map view. But when I put the name changed folder at the same location as original (still keeping the name changed), the map view comes with a off-white color but still doesn't show anything.

Anyone has any idea why this could be happening ?

**Update**: I gave the folder a new name and put it inside another folder the same way I did earlier, but now everything is working :/

So it doesn't work again now.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views
following this tutorial, i had the same issue